# Return value from For loop

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, return

I have a listView in my app. I loop through the items to check which one is currently selected and then return a value. As all paths have to return a value I have to return a value outside the loop which overwrites the for loop return, how do I keep this without overwriting it after the loop?

```
public string GetItemValue()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listView1.Items[i].Checked == true)
        {
            return listView1.Items[i].Text; // I want to keep this value
        }
     }
     // Without overwriting it with this but the compiler 
     // requires me to return a value here
     return "Error"; 
}
```

Any help is most appreciated. Thanks.

P.S I have tried using break after the if but no luck.

Comment: You don't need to worry about this.  As soon as it hits the first ``return`` inside the loop, it will return immediately with that value.  No code outside the loop is ever hit in that case.

Comment: Did you try it out to see what really happens?

Comment: When I run it, it just returns the error text...

Comment: @Bali C Did you check an item?  Break though it to make sure your if statement is following through.

Comment: @BaliC If it returns the Error text, then your `if` condition in the loop is never passing.

Comment: @BishopRook: Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: It won't make any difference, but the `== true` is superfluous.  Just write `if (listView1.Items[i].Checked)`.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, I will try each one and see which one(s) work!

Comment: *Cough* [ListView.SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*On edit*: bringing down my comment from above.

You don't need to worry about this. As soon as it hits the first `return` inside the loop, it will return immediately with that value. No code outside the loop is ever hit in that case.

Incidentally, this code would be cleaner:

```
public string GetItemValue()
{
    foreach (var item in listView1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Checked) return item.Text;
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException("No checked items found");
}
```

Exceptions are a more idiomatic way of handling errors, and the `foreach` loop is preferred to a `for` loop when you're just iterating over collections.

Also using LINQ, you can get even more concise:

```
public string GetItemValue()
{
    return listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Single(i => i.Checked).Text;
}
```

Comment: Change the `new Exception()` to a more specific type, and add a Cast<ListViewItem>() in the second example, and it will be perfect. ;-)

Comment: Good points.  I had forgotten that Windows Forms objects return non-generic containers.  It's sad that all these old widgets are still hanging around with their idiosyncrasies intact!

Answer (score 4):

Well, your return outside of the loop, `return "Error";` shouldn't get called based on your logic. Since `return` causes your method to immediately exit, the "Error" return will never happen, that is unless the code *never* steps into the `if` inside the loop.

All things considered, this may be an *exceptional* case in your code. Thus, throwing an exception may be the appropriate thing to do:

```
public string GetItemValue()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (listView1.Items[i].Checked == true)
                {
                    return listView1.Items[i].Text; // I want to keep this value
                }
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Did not find value expected.");
        }
```

Exceptions are usually thrown to indicate that a bug exists in code. A "Hey, that should really not be happening." The application stops, and hopefully the user gets an opportunity to contact support to help you reproduce it.

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560505/return-value-from-for-loop/7560573#comment-9164804):

> When I run it, it just returns the error text...

That means your check in your `if` statement is not succeeding.

```
if (listView1.Items[i].Checked == true)
```

Which means that none of your items in your ListView are checked.

Answer (score 2):

That's the kind of situations where you are probably better of throwing an exception in order to signal the exceptional situation:

```
public string GetItemValue()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listView1.Items[i].Checked == true)
        {
            // Here you are leaving the GetItemValue method
            // and the loop stops
            return listView1.Items[i].Text;
        }
    }
    // if we get that far it means that none of the items of
    // the select list was actually checked => we are better of
    // reporting this to the caller of the method
    throw new Exception("Please select a value");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The return in your for loop isn't overwritten -- the method will return the value in the loop if your conditions are met. Execution of the method ends immediately upon reaching a `return` statement.

If your method is returning "Error", then I'd recommend looking at your code in a debugger, because it's reaching the end of the loop and returning the value "Error".

Answer (score 2):

If you're returning a value in the loop, it should not reach the return that's outside of the loop. I would check to make sure that the loop is finding the selected item.

The other option is to create a local variable to hold the return value:

```
string returnValue = "Error";

for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++) 
{ 
    if (listView1.Items[i].Checked == true) 
    { 
        returnValue = listView1.Items[i].Text;
        break;
    } 
} 

return returnValue;
```

Lastly, you might also consider returning an exception when no selections are found, and handling the exception from the calling method.

Answer (score 1):

The `return "Error"` bit will not overwrite your loop return value.  When a `return` is hit, the function exits, so when a value that is selected is found, the function will spit out your data and stop.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler requires that all paths of the function return a value. The compiler cannot know before hand whether your inner loop if condition will be met. You can cache the value at a variable and return this in the end of the function e.g. :

```
public string GetItemValue()
    {
        string temp = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listView1.Items[i].Checked == true)
            {
                temp = listView1.Items[i].Text; // I want to keep this value
                break;
            }
        }
        return temp; // Without overwriting it with this but the compiler requires me to return a value here
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong. Compiler will reject this for the same reason as the original code – the `temp` variable has not been definitely assigned a value.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no need for a loop here:

```
return (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    ? listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text
    : "Error";
```

But, as it was said, the original question is misleading since `return` does not override values. You might be thinking about assignment, instead of return. In this case a working code can look like this:

```
string ret = "Error";
foreach(var item in listView1.Items)
{
    if(item.Checked) { ret = item.Text; break; }
}

return ret;
```